# Kivy for web application

Tags: python

New to programming.

I need to code a software/web application which should be used by users without having them installed any IDE to run it. So, I must give them an url that they can execute in their browsers.
I have Anaconda in which I'm using Notebook to execute python 3.7 scripts and just installed Kivy. Can kivy be used for web applications or it's only for desktop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kivy can be used for both desktop applications and for web applications in a notebook. Try it with this [hello world example](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/kivy/kivy/5994/491939788).

Comment: @karel Thanks Karel. Would you mind suggesting any Python's web development framework that is handy and easy to use. I'm still learning what to use either Kivy or Flask.

Comment: Between Flask and Kivy I choose Flask first because it's easier to use. Another package which I like to use for testing code is iPython.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kivy can be used for both desktop applications and for web applications in a notebook. Try it with this [hello world example](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/kivy/kivy/5994/491939788). Between Flask and Kivy I choose Flask first because it's easier to use. Another package which I like to use for testing code is iPython.